# How to get bath screen door (with lip on the edge) to open outwards

Tags: bathtub, screens

I fitted a screen to my bath / shower that has a swinging "door" like panel.

However it can only open inwards. The reason for thus is that I left a distance between the very edge of the bath and fixing as the instructions said - about 15mm, but also have it resting on the wall of the bath. But the top of the bath  wall has a bit of a lip on it so that its highest point is at the outer edge.

So after a bit of searching on the web the door should be able to open outwards for safety and accessibility. The hinge swings both ways but the only way to open it out possible is if I either raise the whole thing about a cm, leaving a large gap underneath, or move it out to the very edge which would get rid of the gap but put it very close to the edge which I am thinking is not advisable (maybe reduces waterproofing etc).

The photo shows what I mean by a lip. As you can see I haven't sealed it yet, pending solving this issue.

So what is the correct way to install a bath screen in this case?

[image: Bath wall with screen]

**Update**

Sorry to have wasted peoples' time - I mis-diagnosed the issue, see my answer below.

Comment: what does a screen do in a shower? is it to stop cats from getting in or something?

Comment: Unless you have 180 dgr door, you installed it the wrong way, left to right. Normally hinges are 90 dgr, but they come in 180 dgr hinges. Which one do you have. Right side door or left side door

Comment: It is a 180º door, it swings out, the problem is the hump at the outer edge of the bath wall is getting in the way.  To be clear - the hinge is not pictured, it's fixed for about 20cm and then the hinge is attached to the outer edge of the fixed panel. The pic is just to show what I meant by a "lip". @dandavis - not sure if that's a joke! But in case it's not, it stops the water getting out! (and looks a bit nicer than a shower curtain)

Comment: Thanks for the update, but please write that up as an Answer, down below, since this was actually an answer to the question. Self-answers are not only OK here, they're encouraged. Also, give yourself a check mark on the answer so others know there's a solution.

Comment: @FreeMan - done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It's now opening out!**  ... but the problem wasn't what I thought.

Further inspection showed there is a bit of clearance between the bottom of the "door" section and the bottom of the fixed panel, which appears to allow for this lip. A flexible fitting underneath this clearance, made it difficult to notice, but it appears my bath isn't square with the wall, so the gap closed further out the door section until the glass was eventually below the lip, making it impossible to open outwards.

Thankfully, it's possible to adjust the entire screen's angle as it fits into the bracket on the wall, and lean it back a little to make this clearance uniform and now the flexible bit rubs over the edge but it can be opened outwards.

Alas it's no longer resting on the side of the bath and so it's a little bit wobbly at the bottom (I've filled up the gap that now appears under the fixed section with silicone sealant)... but that's another story. Also the appearance where it joins to the bracket doesn't look great as it's nowhere near parallel to the bracket and there are two unsightly holes now visible after my original attempt... but anyway... Thanks folks.

Answer (score 3):

Put it on the raised edge of the tub.

`maybe reduces waterproofing etc`

Not really. It puts it on the high point, which improves waterproofing, etc by helping water to drain away from it, and sealing it there is no more difficult than sealing it lower down.

Meanwhile, you don't have to come up with a complicated mess to seal a large gap under it, because it's sitting (on sealant) directly on the high part of the tub lip. Don't move it PAST the high part of the tub lip. You want it **right on top** of that high part.